# How can I change the path of my php.ini conf?

Tags: php.ini, debian-jessie

A few days ago, I compiled PHP 5.5 from sources and installed it on my Debian 8.5 server but I got some issues. I decided to remove it and re-install PHP through package. But I still got issues because the path of my php.ini did not change.

What I actually have is :

```
kevin@debian:~$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File: /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
```

I would like to retrieve a default configuration like this :

```
kevin@debian:~$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/5.6/cli
Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d
```

I tried to re-install php5, php5-fpm... through apt-get but my path never changed.

Is there any command on Debian to change the default path of my php.ini conf ?

Thx.

**Edit :**

which php :

```
kevin@debian:~$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

php -v :

```
kevin@debian:~$ php -v
PHP 5.5.15 (cli)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844641/how-to-change-the-path-to-php-ini-in-php-cli-version

Comment: can you post the output of `which php` and `php --version` here?

Comment: There's already an answer to your question in the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242012) community.

Comment: @mzhaase : Only changed the Loaded Configuration File line.

Comment: @madeddie See my edit

Comment: @Flippy : Tried it, but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default PHP package of Debian installs `php` as `/usr/bin/php` and not in /usr/local/bin/. Also the version will almost always contain a trace of debian:

```
vagrant@jessie:~$ which php
/usr/bin/php
vagrant@jessie:~$ /usr/bin/php --version
PHP 5.6.24-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Jul 26 2016 08:17:07)
```

(see the `deb8u1` in the version string).

You are still using the self-compiled version. Probably /usr/local/bin is earlier in your PATH.

The easiest thing to do is `mv /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php.bak`. This will solve your current problem (you might have to re-login/close your terminal and start it again), but you will want to clean up whatever the compilation and installation process did.

Comment: Comprehensive explanation & worked like a charm. Thank you very much. I will try to clean all my mess now.

Comment: The best explanations come from personal experience ;)